# Tokenize multiple String in array if the input sometimes doesn't have token

Tags: java, android, tokenize

I have input in this form

```
test@test.com
```

and\or in this form

```
test@test.com;test2@test.com
```

or

```
test@test.com;test2@test.com;test3@test.com
```

I should tokenize all, in a String array that contains only a single email for each cell without any separator

```
;
```

Comment: So, you want to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) your [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: Beware: If those are email addresses, wikipedia lists `"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com` as a valid address. In other words, the `;` character might appear in a valid email address. (although, I admit there are probably very few people who actually use it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to tokenize, just use `split`:

```
String[] emails = { "test@test.com;test2@test.com;test3@test.com", "test@test.com"  };
List<string> result = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( string listOfEmails : emails ) {
  for( string email : listOfEmails.split(";") ) {
    result.Add(email).
  }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

And it will work for all cases.

Comment: Thank you! but if the input is a String array?? suppose that contains sometimes cells with a single email and others times strings with a token to separate multiple email and I want to convert this in an array with single mail per cell in this way